# C# A parameter that handles sorting of my list

Tags: c#

I have a program that currently distributes chocolates to x people in a list, and I have a general method that handles the sorting and several methods that orders the list by age, first name etc. depending on how you'd like to distribute the chocolates. My program is working, but is there a way to create ONE method that can take a parameter that handles the sorting? For examle, this is one of the methods that distributes chocolates by **age**:

```
public void DistributeChocolatesByAge(int choc)
{
        People = People.OrderBy(x => x.Age).ToList();
        ChocolatesDistributed(choc);
}
```

ChocolatesDistributed is my "general" distribution method. Is there a way to make my general method take a parameter that handles distribution of chocolates by age (or firstName/lastName) as the method above is doing for me right now? Right now I just have several methods almost doing the same thing.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing not `bool`, needs any type if you want to sort by any property

Comment: @jcl Ah yes, it is sort, not filter

Comment: Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean that you *should*. Doing your sorting like this, with different functions to perform sorts based on different criteria, is actually the right way to do it as in the future you may need to change sort logic for some functions but not for others.

Comment: What does the code that calls DistributeChocolatesByXx look like?

Comment: In essence I'd propose that instead of trying to make some way of having a `DistributeChocolatesByX(people, p =>p.Age)` you can call with this variable second argument to choose something else as an orderby, all that is doing is making some pass-through variation of `DistributeChocolates(people.OrderBy(p=>p.Age))` so you should just skip it, and have the latter

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm not quite sure I understand. I have already tried DistributeChocolates(people.OrderBy(p=>p.Age)) but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you have a method called `DistributeChocolates` that takes an `IEnumerable<Person>` for the people and an `int` number of chocolates? ( Note I simplified my examples and skipped the int of the number of chocolates for each example)

Comment: @CaiusJard My "general" method, DistributeChocolates (int choc) only distributes the choc to the people in my list, so foreach (Person person in People) until there are no chocolates left to distribute.

Comment: and if it took an enumerable of person..

Answer (score 1):

You can make a method passing the `OrderBy` selector via a parameter, something like:

```cs
public void DistributeChocolatesBy<TKey>(Func<TypeOfPeople,TKey> keySelector, int choc) {
  People = People.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();
  ChocolatesDistributed(choc);
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```cs
DistributeChocolatesBy(x => x.Age, 555);
```

Note the `TypeOfPeople` in the parameter, this needs to be the type of your `People` list

Fiddle here (doesn't do anything, just testing it compiles): https://dotnetfiddle.net/zYHJoN

Note that the way this is handled (in your sample code) looks a bit suspicious, but I won't get into your design, just answering your question :-)

Comment: But then the "DistributeChocolatesBy" is little more than an OrderBy, so I don't quite get the point - *I won't get into your design* - I think it makes sense to look at it

Comment: @CaiusJard I agree, I'm not judging the design or code architecture, just answering the general question :-)